# uninstall VSTO plugin

Tags: plugins, vsto, installation, ms-office, uninstallation

When I doubleclick to install a VSTO plugin for Excel 2010 I get a message "unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall the preexisting application.". This plugin was previously uninstalled using "uninstall program" window in control panel. So how do I reinstall the plugin?

I've also deleted the previous plugin from directory that is specified at HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\DownloadCacheLocation registry key.

All exceptions:
*System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException: Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall the preexisting application.*

*at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.DownloadAddIn(TimeSpan timeout)*

*at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you need to do this on a computer without the SDK installed you can run the following command:

```
rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache
```

Source: http://www.nerdfurio.us/blog/post.aspx?id=004f104e-da73-df11-949e-001143eed2d5

Comment: Haven't tried it because I've already solved my problem, but I hope this works and will mark this as a solution.

Comment: Sure, it works. First need to uninstall from Add/Remove Programs, then use this magic command.

Comment: I'd vote you up several times if that was possible - thank you

Answer (score 2):

Another thing you can try: Find the app folder in

`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0`

and delete it.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11921554/15154

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [mage tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx) to clear application cache and that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I've met simple app to remove them:

[image]
 http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto/addin-uninstaller/