# VSTO- Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I have an Outlook VSTO add-in I'm developing. I'm trying to test the ClickOnce deployment, but keep getting the error:

> Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed.

I've manually removed the old version from Outlook's add-in menu. The add-in was also uninstalled via the add/remove programs dialog.

I've also tried the frequently suggested solution to run either of these commands:

```
rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache

mage -cc
```

Both of these commands run fine, but they don't fix the problem. I cannot get the add-in to install no matter what I try.

Does anyone know if there are specific registry settings I could look for to try and manually delete? Or another solution?

Comment: try changing product id

Comment: rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache solved it for me

Answer (score 8):

Find the app folder in:

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0`

and delete it.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11921554/15154

Answer (score 4):

I've run into this before and found that there's a number of places that might be holding it.
Under `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VSTO`, you will also find `\Security\Inclusion\{list of GUIDs}` and `\Security\SolutionMetadata\{list of GUIDs}`.

Check the listed GUIDs under `Security\Inclusion` for a `Url` dword that points to your vsto solution (`file:///C:/Path to VSTO/yourVSTOproject.vsto`) before deleting the {GUID} subkey.
Under the listed GUID keys for `SolutionMetadata`, find the one that lists `yourVSTOproject` by name.
These were two areas that I found some friction at when deploying solutions to an isolated testing machine.

On my development machine, the answer provided by John Fouhy (above) resolved the problem where `rundll dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache` and scrubbing the registry failed.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the key from registry and try to install again

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSTA\Solutions\{GUID}
```

Please verify product name DWORD value before you delete